# Cakephp foreach

Tags: cakephp, foreach

When I use foreach to show the my value in the base it show me a false value
in the controller:

```
    public function index_hote() {
    $this->Reservation->recursive = 1;
    $this->loadModel("Bien");
    $biens=$this->Bien->find('first',array('conditions'=>array("Bien.idBien     =idBien")));
     $reservations=$this->Reservation-   >find('first',
     array('conditions'=>array('Reservation.idBien'=> $biens['Bien'] ['idBien'])));
      Debugger::dump($reservations['Reservation']);
    $this->paginate('Reservation');
   $this->set('reservations', $reservations['Reservation']);

    }
```

In the view:

```
    <?php foreach ($reservations as $reservation): ?>
     <tr>   
     <?php echo h($reservation) ?>
     <td><?php echo h($reservation['dateReserDu']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($reservation['dateReserAu']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($reservation['montantAPaye']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><?php echo h($reservation['etatReservation']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I debug it shows me the right value (the pic after doing `Debugger::dump($reservations['Reservation']);`):

[image: the pic after doing Debugger::dump($reservations['Reservation']);]

but in the table it shows me a false value:

[image: pic of the false value]

When I do `<?php echo h($reservation) ?>` it shows me the right value but when I add a attribute such as `h($reservation['dateReserDu']); ?>` it doesn't work PLZ why? And when can I do?

Comment: Please show us what you just `debug($reservation);` cheers

Comment: array( 'Reservation' => array( 'idReser' => '1',
'dateReserDu' => '2016-04-23', 'dateReserAu' => '2016-04-27',
'montantAPaye' => '500','etatReservation' => 'attente',
'iddev' => '0','idBien' => '9',
'id' => '24'),
 'Personne' => array( 'login' => '*****', 'id' => '24','designation' => 'client','nom' => 'mohamed','prenom' => 'jmaa',
'dateNaiss' => '1991-07-22',
  'adresse' => 'rue paris',
  'telFixe' => '26119945',
  'telMobile1' => '95632114',
  'telMobile2' => '98745213',
  'email' => 'wahibaml@gmail.com',
  'mdp' => '26111991',
  'lienPhotoPersonnel' => 'sou.jpg',
  'idVille' => '14'
 ),
 
)

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using loop here ? You have used `find('first')` to retrieve one data see
[doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first) .

If you want to retrieve all data use `find('all')`. However if you want to `echo` your find 1st data just use below structure

```
$this->set('reservations', $reservations);
```

In view

`echo $reservations['Reservation']['Your_field_name'];`

Comment: if i do echo $reservations['Reservation']['Your_field_name'];
 i have the same probleme :(

Comment: Did you change $this->set , that I have mention ? and did you remove foreach loop ?

Comment: If you got ans , please receive this as an answer.

Comment: if i don't use foreach it show me just one line what can i do to show the all line ?

Comment: Use find('all') , not find('first') , see doc that I have given ref 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-first
find first fetch single data not all data.

Comment: i would have the the idBien of the table Reservation equals to the idBien in the table Bien but i have many Bien. what should i write in the condition        $reservations=$this->Reservation->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Reservation.idBien'=> $biens[0]['Bien']['idBien])));   when i write $biens[0]['Bien']['idBien] it take juste the first Bien

Comment: If you use find all then you have to use loop.Read doc again.

Comment: yeah i use loop but i have  problems .  this is my problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830885/cakephp-foreach-condition